# Tridion 2009 SP1: Dreamweaver Template Error: ConvertURLToPath() can't decode URL: invalid escape

Tags: tridion, dreamweaver-templates

I'm trying to use a Get Label TBB in a Dreamweaver Template that parses expressions like `%%LabelKey%%` and replaces them with a value from a Component that is stored in Publication metadata.

I'm trying to use a label to store an absolute URL (e.g. http://www.example.com) but am getting the following in Template Builder when trying to run the template

> Error: ConvertURLToPath() can't decode URL: invalid escape

The DWT code looks similar to:

```
<a href="%%LogoLink%%" target="_blank" title="%%LogoLinkTitle%%" class="logo">
    <img src="@@Page.Publication.Metadata.parent_logo@@" width="95" height="24"
         alt="@@parent_logo0.alt@@">
</a>
```

The problem is caused by `%%LogoLink%%`. If I remove that the template works fine. Why is Tridion trying to do something with this value? I thought it would only try and resolve it if it was `tridion:href`.

Any help appreciated.

Full stack trace:

> Engine: Error in Engine.Transform Error: ConvertURLToPath() can't
>   decode URL: invalid escape    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetTcmUri(String uri)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetObject(String uri)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Session.IsExistingObject(String uri)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.GetObject(Session session,
>   String itemUriOrWebDavUrl)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.GetObject(String
>   itemUriOrWebDavUrl)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Templates.ExtractBinariesFromHtmlTemplate.ResolveWebDavUrl(String
>   urlToResolve, String webDavBaseUrl, Engine engine)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Templates.ExtractBinariesFromHtmlTemplate.ResolveTemplateBinaries(Engine
>   engine, Package package, TcmUri baseItemTcmUri,
>   ExtractBinariesContentWrapper contentWrapper)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Templates.ExtractBinariesFromHtmlTemplate.Transform(Engine
>   engine, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator.RegisterTemplateBinaries(Package
>   package, String baseItemTcmUri, String templateString)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator.Transform(Engine
>   engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template
>   template, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package
>   package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
>   at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine
>   engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template
>   template, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package
>   package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
>   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template
>   template, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformItem(Template
>   template, IdentifiableObject itemToRender)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebuggingEngine.Run()
>   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebugSession.Run()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you upload a DWT Tridion tries to map that `<img src=...` in your DWT to a Multimedia Component. This step is needed to ensure that a DWT works fine with BluePrinting (which requires the values to stored as TCM URIs) **AND** is always viewable in Dreamweaver (which requires file paths).

To do this mapping, Tridion takes the path in any `src` or `href` attributes (as well as any CSS import or `url()` construct) and looks for a Multimedia Component in that location relative to the DWT.

So if a DWT that is stored under `/Building Blocks/System/Designs/My Page Design` and it contains:

```
<img src="../Images/MyHeader.jpg"></img>
```

Then Tridion will look for a Multimedia Component called `/Building Blocks/System/Images/MyHeader.jpg` and replace the `src` value if it finds a match:

```
<img src="tcm:1-23"></img>
```

In your DWT the `%%LogoLink%%` is causing problems, since it looks like it is URL-encoded (the % sign is used as an escape character in URLs), but in reality isn't.

Most people encountering similar problems end up using an alternate escape sequence in their DWT and write a small post-processing TBB that converts that escape sequence back into %% after the DWT is executed. In your case just picking a non-conflicting escape syntax would be enough.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I assume you mean src= and href=? I will look at creating the small TBB that seems like a sensible solution.

Comment: Sorry, I have a habit of posting my answer and then improving it. ;-)   Tridion indeed processes all `src` and `href` attributes, CSS imports and CSS `url()`s. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Puf I have implemented a 5 line TBB which does the job.

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by @Puf explains why the code fails very well. As an alternative approach, you might consider writing a C# TBB that inserts StringItems into the package called 'LogoLink' and 'LogoLinkTitle' containing your URL and text. You can then use the new TBB before the DWT in the pipeline, and then insert the values using the standard DWT syntax as follows:

```
 <a href="@@LogoLink@@" target="_blank" title="@@LogoLinkTitle@@" class="logo">
     <img src="@@Page.Publication.Metadata.parent_logo@@" width="95" height="24" alt="@@parent_logo0.alt@@">
 </a>
```

Perhaps there is a reason you have not done this, in which case go with Franks solution.

Comment: The only reason I haven't done that is because I'd assumed my solution would just work with labels, this sounds like another reasonable solution.